# How to dynamically populate list items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I'm setting up an image slider with thumbnail slider using this plugin in React.js: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

If I add the `<li>`s statically it works perfectly fine:

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="slide4.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However if I try to load the content dynamically, the inline styles that are dynamically calculated and added by the plugin code won't be added to both `ul` and `li` elements (i.e `width: 210px; margin-right: 5px; float: left; display: block;`)

This is how I do it:

```
render() {

  if(this.props.data){
    var projects = this.props.data.projects.map(function(projects){
    var projectImage = 'images/portfolio/'+projects.image;

    return <li key={projects.title}>
             <img alt={projects.title} src={projectImage} />
           </li>
    })
  }

  return (
    <section id="portfolio">
      <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
          {projects}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it a react plugin or an external plugin? The issue could be that the js of the plugin starts before that react mounts the elements, and the elements are not there so the js of the plugins don't work

Comment: It's an external plugin (I've added the link at the top). So is there a way to make the plugin run after elements are mounted by react? (i.e componentDidMount?)

Comment: where do you do `$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link that you gave, the plugin requires initialization. Where are you doing your initialization?

I would recommend doing the initialization in the `componentDidMount` life cycle method. This is because when that code runs the `<li>` would have already been in DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the initialization code in the file init.js which was then called in the index.html

`<script src="js/init.js"></script>`

following your suggestion, I added

`$(window).load(function() {` before the initialization code and now it works! Thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Besides, you don't need to add the event listener on the window object in the `componentDidMount` function. You could directly just write the `$('#carousel').flexslider({ ...` in that.